# Yii2:advanced - several backends

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I want to create several backends.
For example:

```
Default yii2 advanced project

project/
.. backend/
.. common/
.. console/
.. frontend/
```

I need:

```
project/
.. backend1/
    .. controllers/
    .. modules/
.. backend2    /
    .. controllers/
    .. modules/
```

Its really?
The web-site may consist of several subprograms

```
backend/
 b1/
   controllers
   modules
   views
 b2/
  controlles
  modules
  views
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Yii2 advanced app you can have as many apps as you want, i.e. backend1, backend2, frontend1, frontendXY, api, etc... you name it.

Here is little guide how to do it: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/topic-adding-more-apps.md